# Will x86 UWP package on store visible to x64 machines?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-universal

Will x86 package uploaded on windows store (UWP) also work/ be visible from x64 machine? In case there is no x64 package uploaded for the same.

Answer (score 1):

An x86 should be able to install on x64 device through the store, I haven't tried it. The other way round won't work.

When creating an app package, you should select all 3 (x86, x64, ARM) platforms if you want all devices to be able to install your app. I see no reason to not do this.

> 6. Make sure you select all three architecture configurations (x86, x64, and ARM) in the Select and Configure Packages dialog. That way your app can be deployed to the widest range of devices.

[image]

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454036.aspx